# echo inside another echo

Tags: php, html

I have this div container echoed using EOS

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM anuncio");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo <<<EOS
            <div class="contentBox">
                <div id="column1">
                    <img src="images/gallery/girlthinking.jpg" alt="" id="imagen">
                </div>

                <div id="column2">
                    <p class="tituloanuncio"><b>title</b></p>
                    <p class="descripcionanuncio">description</p>
                </div>

                <div id="column3">
                    <p class="precioanuncio"><b>$1000</b></p>
                    <p class="contactoanuncio"><b>Contacto<br></b>Dueño: Alejandro<br>Telefono: 8331578460<br>jorgegilcavazos@gmail.com<br>Facebook</p>
                </div>
            </div>
EOS;
}
```

I would like to replace "title" and "description" with $row['title']; and $row['description'];
How do i do this without messing up the div?

Comment: Possible duplicate of the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @PeeHaa duplicate of the manual? really ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Echo inside and Echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720247/echo-inside-and-echo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put them in there, and put `{`curly braces`}` around them:

```
echo <<<EOS
            <div class="contentBox">
                <div id="column1">
                    <img src="images/gallery/girlthinking.jpg" alt="" id="imagen">
                </div>

                <div id="column2">
                    <p class="tituloanuncio"><b>{$row['title']}</b></p>
                    <p class="descripcionanuncio">{$row['description']}</p>
                </div>

                <div id="column3">
                    <p class="precioanuncio"><b>$1000</b></p>
                    <p class="contactoanuncio"><b>Contacto<br></b>Dueño: Alejandro<br>Telefono: 8331578460<br>jorgegilcavazos@gmail.com<br>Facebook</p>
                </div>
            </div>
EOS;
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM anuncio");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo <<<EOS
            <div class="contentBox">
                <div id="column1">
                    <img src="images/gallery/girlthinking.jpg" alt="" id="imagen">
                </div>

                <div id="column2">
                    <p class="tituloanuncio"><b>{$row['title']}</b></p>
                    <p class="descripcionanuncio">description</p>
                </div>

                <div id="column3">
                    <p class="precioanuncio"><b>$1000</b></p>
                    <p class="contactoanuncio"><b>{$row['description']}<br></b>Dueño: Alejandro<br>Telefono: 8331578460<br>jorgegilcavazos@gmail.com<br>Facebook</p>
                </div>
            </div>
EOS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't. Just exit php mode and go back into html mode.

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM anuncio");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>

    <div class="contentBox">
        <div id="column1">
            <img src="images/gallery/girlthinking.jpg" alt="" id="imagen">
        </div>

        <div id="column2">
            <p class="tituloanuncio"><b><?=$row['title'] ?></b></p>
            <p class="descripcionanuncio"><?=$row['description'] ?></p>
        </div>

        <div id="column3">
            <p class="precioanuncio"><b>$1000</b></p>
            <p class="contactoanuncio"><b>Contacto<br></b>Dueño: Alejandro<br>Telefono: 8331578460<br>jorgegilcavazos@gmail.com<br>Facebook</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<? php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: As you should already know, i'm a noob at this so can you tell me if and why is this better than echoing html like the others answered? It works both ways.

Comment: It keeps your html code separated from your php code. So when you need to switch over to a more formal templating system, your life is easier. When you have a syntax error in php, your life is easier finding it. So your variables are kept in one place, outside of the markup. Look at common MVC patterns for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess up your html, you should make sure that your values cannot do that by encoding them correctly with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Then you can inject them safely in your html, using either a heredoc or concatenating strings:

```
$title = htmlspecialchars($row['title']);
$description = htmlspecialchars($row['description']);

echo <<<EOS
        <div class="contentBox">
            <div id="column1">
                <img src="images/gallery/girlthinking.jpg" alt="" id="imagen">
            </div>

            <div id="column2">
                <p class="tituloanuncio"><b>{$title}</b></p>
                <p class="descripcionanuncio">{$description}</p>
            </div>

            <div id="column3">
                <p class="precioanuncio"><b>$1000</b></p>
                <p class="contactoanuncio"><b>Contacto<br></b>Dueño: Alejandro<br>Telefono: 8331578460<br>jorgegilcavazos@gmail.com<br>Facebook</p>
            </div>
        </div>
EOS;
}
```